# Assembly location not showing after Assembly.LoadFile in Mono C#

Tags: c#, reflection, mono

if I do this in Mono (on Ubuntu):

```
Assembly asb = Assembly.LoadFile("/home/ben/Documents/aDll.dll");
```

then asb.Location==""

If I do the same thing on Windows it returns the location of the file.

Is this a bug in Mono or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Under Mono 4.8.x I get the properly location after a successful `LoadFile`... Which version of Mono are you using? Is the `LoadFile` actually successful? Are `CodeBase` & `EscapedCodeBase` empty?

Comment: Mono 4.8.0.520.
Pretty sure the load has been successful, CodeBase and EscapedCodeBase are not empty. A Module has been loaded